# formating columns with str.rsplit changes some column names to NAN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, rename

I have a data set with column names similar to the following but with many more "messy" columns

```
name    info    date    pb.l.what_i_want_.n    pb.l.what_i_want_.d    pb.....
```

My goal is to rename the messy columns and keep only 'what_i_want'

I used `df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('.').str[1]` but that changed the first 3 column names to NAN

I have tried using a for loop

```
for col in df.columns[3:]:
    df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('.').str[1]
```

an if statement

```
if '.' in df.columns:
    df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('.').str[1]
```

and a combo

```
for col in df.columns:
    if '.' in col:
        df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('.').str[1]
```

but when I run it any of these ways at best it runs but does not apply `rsplit` to any of the columns and at worst I get `'str' object has no attribute 'str'` as an error depending on the exact code (I tried it many ways).

After failing to come up with a solution I decided to just manually rename the columns using

```
df = df.rename(columns= {df.columns[0]: 'name', df.column[1]: 'info', df.columns[2]: 'date'})
```

However this changed all 3 columns to 'name'

I also tried using `df.rename` 3 separate times, but that resulted in the same problem.

If I switch the order so that `df.columns[1]: 'info'` is first, all of the names change to 'info' and the same for 'date' if `df.columns[2]` is first

Ideally I would like a solution that only applies `rsplit` to the desired columns so I do not have to re enter the column names.

Here is an example of an actual column name:

```
tpm.ARPE-19_EMT_induced_with_TGF-beta_and_TNF-alpha_03hr00min_biol_rep3.CNhs14493.13654-147B9.hg38.nobarcode
```

The part I want to keep is

```
ARPE-19_EMT_induced_with_TGF-beta_and_TNF-alpha_03hr00min_biol_rep3
```

Comment: What will be the updated column names, can u include that in the post.

Comment: You are modifying your columns as many times as number of columns in all of your `for` loops. That being said, when, eventually, there is nothing for `str[1]` to grab, it will yield `NaN`. In addition, when you split `name` with `.`, what do yo expect to be a second element (i.e. `str[1]`)?

Comment: str[1] gives me 'what_i_want' which is the what I want the column names to be when i am done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) along with the given `regex` pattern to extract the column names from messy column names, then use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to select columns from `df.columns` and `cols`, depending upon the condition where extracted columns is not `NaN`:

```
cols = df.columns.str.extract(r'\.([^\.]+)\.', expand=False)
df.columns = np.where(cols.notna(), cols, df.columns)
```

Example `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'info', 'date', 'pb.l.what_i_want_.n', 'pb.l.what_i_want_.d' ])
```

Result:

```
# print(df.columns)
Index(['name', 'info', 'date', 'what_i_want_', 'what_i_want_'], dtype='object')
```

Regex explanation:

1. `\.` matches the character `.` literally.
2. 1st Capturing Group `([^\.]+)`

   - Match a single character **not** present in the list below `[^\.]+`
   - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work. When I `print(df.columns)` all column names (except first 3) are 'hg38'. I believe its because my column names are different then the examples I provided so I edited the question to include an example of the actual column name and the part I want to keep. How would you edit the regex to make it work for these names? I have never used a regex before so I am not sure what to change.

Comment: Yes! that worked! Thank you! would you mind explaining a little bit about the regex and what each character does?

Comment: Thank you so much!!